# How to display only certain x axis values on plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting values from a dataframe where time is the x-axis. The time is formatted as 00:00 to 23:45. I only want to display the specific times 00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00 on the x-axis of my plot. How can this be done? I have posted two figures, the first shows the format of my dataframe after setting the index to time. And the second shows my figure. Thank you for your help!

```
monday.set_index("Time", drop=True, inplace=True)

monday_figure = monday.plot(kind='line', legend = False, 
                            title = 'Monday Average Power consumption')
monday_figure.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(8))
```

Edit: Adding data as text:

```
Time,DayOfWeek,kW
00:00:00,Monday,5.8825
00:15:00,Monday,6.0425
00:30:00,Monday,6.0025
00:45:00,Monday,5.7475
01:00:00,Monday,6.11
01:15:00,Monday,5.8025
01:30:00,Monday,5.6375
01:45:00,Monday,5.85
02:00:00,Monday,5.7250000000000005
02:15:00,Monday,5.66
02:30:00,Monday,6.0025
02:45:00,Monday,5.71
03:00:00,Monday,5.7425
03:15:00,Monday,5.6925
03:30:00,Monday,5.9475
03:45:00,Monday,6.380000000000001
04:00:00,Monday,5.65
04:15:00,Monday,5.8725
04:30:00,Monday,5.865
04:45:00,Monday,5.71
05:00:00,Monday,5.6925
05:15:00,Monday,5.9975000000000005
05:30:00,Monday,5.905000000000001
05:45:00,Monday,5.93
06:00:00,Monday,5.6025
06:15:00,Monday,6.685
06:30:00,Monday,7.955
06:45:00,Monday,8.9225
07:00:00,Monday,10.135
07:15:00,Monday,12.9475
07:30:00,Monday,14.327499999999999
07:45:00,Monday,14.407499999999999
08:00:00,Monday,15.355
08:15:00,Monday,16.2175
08:30:00,Monday,18.355
08:45:00,Monday,18.902499999999996
09:00:00,Monday,19.0175
09:15:00,Monday,20.0025
09:30:00,Monday,20.355
09:45:00,Monday,20.3175
10:00:00,Monday,20.8025
10:15:00,Monday,20.765
10:30:00,Monday,21.07
10:45:00,Monday,19.9825
11:00:00,Monday,20.94
11:15:00,Monday,22.1325
11:30:00,Monday,20.6275
11:45:00,Monday,21.4475
12:00:00,Monday,22.092499999999998
```

[image: Dataframe after setting index]

[image: Plot with incorrect x-axis values]

[image: Figure after adding coding from comment below]

The image above is produced using the code from the comment below.

Comment: You should not include a picture of your dataframe Copy and paste the data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a [datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) using `pd.to_datetime` when plotting timeseries.
I then used `matplotlib.mdates` to detect the desired ticks and format them in the plot. I don't know if it can be done from pandas with `df.plot`.
See [matplotlib date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html). You can customize the HourLocator or use a different locator to suit your needs. Minor ticks are created the same way with `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator`. Hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Using your dataframe
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

# Make sure you have a datetime index
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(df['kW'])
# Use mdates to detect hours
locator = mdates.HourLocator(byhour=[0,6,12,18])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
# Format x ticks
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

# rotates and right aligns the x labels, and moves the bottom of the axes up to make room for them
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: The graph displays, but now the plot has no values on the x axis, just a label that says "Time".Thank you for the help, it is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with the conversion to datetime index. In my case, time was put in as a string and then converted to a datetime index with pandas. It seems that your time was created with `datetime.time` and you don't have a proper datetime index which would explain why no values are showing. Can you check your `df.info()`?   
My output:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>   
RangeIndex: 49 entries, 0 to 48   
Data columns (total 3 columns):   
Time         49 non-null datetime64[ns]   
...

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but if you can't fix the `datetime.time` before you create the dataframe, replace the pd.to_datetime line with this:
`df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))`